# Display UIAlertView BEFORE didFinishLaunchingWithOptions completes?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

My app performs time-consuming one-time initialization in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**. I would like to display an alert, **UIAlertView**, to inform the user about this condition, but the alert never shows up until **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** completes, even if shown with `[alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];`.

Moving one-time initialization to post- **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is not possible, due to the fact that **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** has to set the main window's root view controller, which needs the initialization. Setting up a throw-away (dummy) root view controller in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, covered or replaced later, seems somewhat... inelegant.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before, with one particular app.

The only way to solve it is with a "dummy" root view controller.

What I've done was to make a view controller with a `UIImageView`, add that `UIImageView` the launch image and an activity indicator.

Note that an activity indicator don't have to be a `UIActivityIndicatorView`; activity indicator is just a concept.

In my case I had a label and a progress bar. I would update the progress bar trough out the loading process, and change the label text to indicate the user what the app was doing.

Also, I advise you not to use the alert view; it's to intrusive.

Comment: A creative idea, but right after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you might, or might not, receive `applicationDidBecomeActive`, unfortunately before `[self performSelector:@selector(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions_stage2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0]`, which complicates the flow of control with respect to the expected application state. Oh, boy...

Comment: @Gary - it's kind of a catch-22.  We need UI to show that we're doing a fetch that initializes UI.  rtiago42's idea is not only a good idea, it's the only way out.  I don't think it's inelegant either.  The app should always present it's state to the user, including the "I don't know my state yet" state.

Comment: @danh - iOS really should differentiate between frame-based UI (a launch image) and frame-less UI (a UIAlertView on top of a launch image), just like most other UI toolkits :).

Comment: @rtiago42 - it is only after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well as `applicationDidBecomeActive` (an app completely in the foreground) that a `UIAlertView` will be displayed by iOS. The second stage of application initialization (the main window root view controller replacement) can be scheduled in `applicationDidBecomeActive` for a predictable notification ordering.

Comment: @Gary Don't forget that `applicationDidBecomeActive` may be called without a call to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`; the app could come from the background. Personally, whenever I feel the need for a "splash screen", I make the view controller responsible for setting the new root view controller. You can make your SplashScreenController the app's delegate, doing so will keep the delegate responsible for the window's management.